# Locate all row and column pairs containing a value in a table

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, output-formatting

I would like to find all row and column pairs that contain 1 in a table.  For example, the row and column pairs that contain 1 in the table are (a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b),(c,d),(d,c),(d,e),and (e,d).

```
TableForm[Table[Abs[i - j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}], TableHeadings -> {{a, b, c, d, e}, {a, b, c, d, e}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table = Table[Abs[i - j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];

rc = Position[table, 1] /. n_Integer :> {a, b, c, d, e}[[n]]

(* {{a, b}, {b, a}, {b, c}, {c, b}, {c, d}, {d, c}, {d, e}, {e, d}} *)
```

Comment: Bob: Very efficient!! ... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
A = Table[Abs[i - j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
{i, j} = Transpose[Position[A, 1]];
rowtitles = {a, b, c, d, e};
coltitles = {a, b, c, d, e};
Transpose[{rowtitles[[i]], coltitles[[j]]}]
```

Comment: Henrik: Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!